# Speech Recognition in Windows Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-recognition

can anyone help me on the same?
I need some clarification about Windows Server 2008/2012 in which we need Speech recognition feature though we have developed a software (Psychometric test battery) which is going to be used by Visually Impaired people, but we couldn't make it run in Server (where we used to HOST).
And here is the conv with our cloud service provider;
Initially they have mentioned that; WinSvr 2008 will provide the feature;so we planned to downgrade from WinSvr2012, for that we had a test VM to check the same, but it didn't get works, and the reply for the same form them is;
We regret to inform you that speech Recognition application is only available to Client Operating system's like windows 7/8/10, Not server Server Operating systems.
Speech recognition is not included in "Desktop experience feature" in server level. Please find the Microsoft Documentation for the same.
And is there any alternatives to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different API. Don't use the "[Desktop API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663(v=vs.85).aspx) / [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361625(v=office.14).aspx)", but use the server version, the [Speech platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd266409(v=office.14).aspx).

**.NET**:

This programming guide provides an introduction to developing speech applications for the Windows **Desktop** using the System.Speech namespaces in the Microsoft .NET Framework.

**Speech platform**:

```
Development of speech-enabled applications is supported on:
Windows Vista or later 
Windows 2003 Server or later 
Windows 2008 Server or later
```

```
Deployment of speech-enabled applications is supported on: 
Windows 2003 Server or later 
Windows 2008 Server or later
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362873%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank U, will check & get back